# php string-to-date manipulation with POST data

Tags: php, date

I am posting data from a form to a PHP script.

All is working fine except for this.

- First field is `date1` and the date is written as `20140720` (2014
  July 20th)
- Second field is called `date2`
- Third field is called `type`
- Fourth field is called `code`

---

```
$type = $_POST['type']

$date1 = $_POST['yearfield'] . $_POST['dayfield'] . $_POST['monthfield'];
$date2 = $_POST['date2'] ;
$code = $_POST['code'];

if ($type == '6') {$code = '6';}
```

If `$type == 6` then change `$code` and also change `$date2` to a number that corresponds to 14 days later.

In the example above `$date2` would become `20140803` (August 3rd), 14 days later than July 20th.

Comment: You may wish to consider these code changes - http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25340140/3 your `$type = $_POST['type']` is missing a terminator `;` editor also suggests expanding your `if` statement so it's more readable.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Well after your edit it is little bit more simple:

```
$date2 = strtotime( $date1 . ' +14 days' );
```

---

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) function. It would look something like this:

```
$date2 = date( 'F jS', strtotime( $date1 . ' +14 days' ) );
```

which would in your case print: **August 3rd**
and you can just add the rest:

```
$date2 = strtotime( $date1 . ' +14 days' ).' '.$date2.', 14 days later than .'$date1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the date1 format to be Y-m-d to be easy to handle & then, it would be easy to modify no.of days

```
<?php
$date1 = $_POST['yearfield'] . "-" . $_POST['monthfield'] . "-" . $_POST['dayfield']; //format like 2000-01-11
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); //set this timezone
$date = new DateTime($date1);  
$date->add(new DateInterval('P14D')); //this means add 14 days
$date2 = $date->format('Ymd'); //format would be like this
```